# How to get selected item from AutoSuggestBox in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In CS File "SelectedItem" is not working what is the alternative to "SelectedItem" for AutoSuggestBox in WP8.1

In XAML File:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="tblkpersonname" Width="380" Margin="0,-7,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" TextChanged="tblkpersonname_TextChanged">
                <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Tag="{Binding PersonID}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            </AutoSuggestBox>
```

In Cs File:

```
 private void tblkpersonname_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (tblkpersonname.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                tblkdes.Text = ((values)tblkpersonname.SelectedItem).Description;
                persononlineimg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(((values)tblkpersonname.SelectedItem).FlickrPersonImageUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exceptions.SaveOrSendExceptions("Exception in tblkpersonname_SelectionChanged_1 Method In AddCast.cs file.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no "SelectedItem" in the AutoSuggestBox provided with Windows Phone 8.1 and neither there's one in the developer tools for Windows 10.
The AutoSuggestBox works like a regular TextBox, the only plus here's the possibility to have a panel/popup that show ups for giving suggestions based on the ItemsSource you passed.
Actually it only works if the ItemsSource is a collection of string, since the DisplayMemberPath doesn't work, at least for me.
So the only way to retrieve the "SelectedItem" you should use the Text property.
I know it's not actually the same, but the AutoSuggestBox it's not a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Xaml

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

<AutoSuggestBox
    Text="{Binding EnteredAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AddressAutoComplete}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Autocomplete}" 
    TextMemberPath="name">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SuggestionChosen">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextSearchChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding this}">
            </core:InvokeCommandAction>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

ViewModel (Prism)

```
TextSearchChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<Object>((Object) =>
{
    method(Object);
});

public void method(Object adr)
{
    AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs a = (AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs)adr;
    Address selected = (Address)a.SelectedItem;
}
```

I spent a whole day to realize it:-)